# Undefined is not a function (react-native-cli)

Tags: react-native

I have a problem where I wanted to add a stack screen as a login page in app.js. However, the problem pops up like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBgEY.png). The tab view works well, but when I change it with stackScreen, it shows the problem.

What can be a solution?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the code that causes the error and the error message as text, not as an image. As it is, the error is cut off, and no one can see what is wrong. Please also check [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: The only thing that can be inferred from what you shared is that you think something is a function, it's not and you're calling it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.